# Getting the latest outgoing transaction of an Ethereum address

Tags: infura, api

I'm trying to write a code to get the latest outgoing transaction of an Ethereum address data. For that I reached to Infura and tried to get it using something like this:

```
const INFURA_URL = 'https://mainnet.infura.io/v3/INFURA_PROJECT_ID'
const address = "some ethereum address"
const handleReq = async(event) =>{
 event.preventDefault();
 try{
  const response = await axios.get('${INFURA_URL}/eth/v1/address/${address}');
  const transaction = response.data.data;
 } catch(error){ console.error(error);}
```

but the code gives me the 404 error that 'response' variable is not valid. I wanted to ask if you have experience with infura and help me if the way I try to address the account is valid and correct. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

usually I don't use RPC node services like Infura as it is a bit cumbersome now that there are several API services out there that makes it easy to index these data with a few lines of code.

One service that I recommend is Moralis, and for getting latest outgoing transaction of an address, you have two options from Moralis, Web3 API (for non real-time) and Streams API (for real-time).

With Web3 API, if you don't need to get real-time data, then you can fetch the latest transaction of an address using Moralis [`getWalletTransactions`](https://docs.moralis.io/web3-data-api/reference/get-wallet-transactions) API and will just need to provide a valid `address` input to the API.

On the other hand, if you need to get real-time data, such as getting transaction notification, then you can setup Streams with Moralis that will monitor any transaction of an address real-time and send those data to your webhooks.

To get to know more about Streams API, check [here](https://docs.moralis.io/streams-api) on how to setup one.